# I can scrape a whole page in Scrapy but failed to using xpath find a DOM element

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a complete beginner in Python and I want to use scrapy for scraping some image from [Baidu Image.](http://image.baidu.com/channel?c=%E7%BE%8E%E5%A5%B3)

I can easily get a whole page with tutorial:

```
with open('baiduImage.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.body)
```

It seems a complete page with all element performed well in Chrome, but I failed to using

```
f.write(response.xpath('/html/body').extract()[0].encode('utf8'))
```

to get a whole body, it lost all the images! I checked the file and I found some part of it was lost. Did I make any mistake?I guess the reason is the page is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the reason you are not getting the same HTML you see in the browser is that the page is loaded dynamically with a set of XHR calls and javascript logic that a browser would apply.

Here are the options you have:

- use the [site's API](http://developer.baidu.com/wiki/index.php?title=docs) instead of the web-scraping approach
- use Scrapy with [`scrapyjs`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs)
- automate a real browser with the help of [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)
- inspect how the page is loaded and simulate the requests being sent in your code